# Implement normal scrolling in React, or how to use fullPage.js with React

Tags: reactjs, fullpage.js

I've Googled around about this quite a bit already but I haven't found a definitive, easy-to-implement answer and I'm wondering if someone here could help.

I want to use fullPage.js with React but the npm packages I have seen don't seem to have all the features of fullPage.js such as scrolling normally within a section.

I am currently using React-fullpage but I really need the feature I just mentioned and I don't see React-fullpage having it. Maybe I'm missing something.

I'm wondering how I can implement that or what the best way is to use fullPage.js with React.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda old but if anyone was looking for a solution, then just use `autoScrolling={false}`.

Here's an example: [this was not written by me though](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-smoke-zmzj6?file=/src/pages/index.js:495-516)